# How to assign server side value to ng-model input fields in angular js 1.x without using model name assignment in controller script

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

is anyway for direct assignment of server side value to ng-model input  fields? I want edit a form its value are coming through server using php   but when i assign to input field value but that didn't appear  there.

```
 <form name="userForm"  method="post" action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate> 

  <input md-maxlength="70" required="" name="firsname" ng-model="user.name"  value="<?php echo $name;?>">

  </form>
```

I know this method,but it is not practical in my application,so any one know how to assign  server side value using above method

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "<?php echo $name;?>";
});
</script>
```

Comment: since, `ng-value` didnt work for you. Can you confirm whether you are able to render and see `<?php echo $name;?>` on the `html` page ?

Comment: Yes i print on html page then i get the value

Comment: One more thing  i use Angular js materialize   design  so it will  cause any trouble? reff Link:https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Comment: Hmmm, can u try and see if plain `ng-model` works or not with `ng-value` ?  if not, then I'll share one workaround.

Comment: using PHP for rendering already is a problem, why can't you pull it with a http request? AngularJS has `$http` service for that. E.g. `$http.get(url).then((res) => {$scope.name = res.data})`

Comment: i tried   plain  ng-model.The problem is   I am using  Angular materialize.I cant use json data  that is the main problem